# NGINX configuration for Nuxt

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js

Looking for an NGINX configuration for Nuxt APP.
So far in my progress, It seems that I have a binding port issue because already mapped.

Tried the doc example and many more but nothing seems to work.

Procfile : `web: bin/start-nginx nuxt start`

This is my node server configuration :

```js
import express from 'express'
import fs from 'fs'

const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
export default function () {
  const app = express()

  const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
    const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

    const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

    nuxt.ready().then(() => {
      // Give nuxt middleware to express
      app.use(nuxt.render)

      // Listen the server
      // app.listen(port, host, () => {})

      app.listen('/tmp/nginx.socket', () => {
        console.log("Signalling nginx buildpack to start listening")
        fs.openSync('/tmp/app-initialized', 'w')
      })
    })
 }
```

Here is the NGINX configuration located in config/nginx.conf.erb

```
daemon off;
#Heroku dynos have at least 4 cores.
worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>;

events {
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex on;
    worker_connections <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKER_CONNECTIONS'] || 1024 %>;
}

http {
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 512;

    server_tokens off;

    log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_x_request_id';
    access_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ACCESS_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/access.log' %> l2met;
    error_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ERROR_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/error.log' %>;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;

    #Must read the body in 5 seconds.
    client_body_timeout 5;

    upstream app_server {
        server unix:/tmp/nginx.socket fail_timeout=0;
    }

    map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
        "text/html"                 epoch;
        "text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch;
        default                     off;
    }

    server {
        listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
        server_name localhost;
        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Found you any solution?

Comment: Yes looks answer bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS :

```
import express from 'express'
import fs from 'fs'
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
export default function () {
   const app = express()

   const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
     // Init Nuxt.js
     const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

     const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

     nuxt.ready().then(() => {
       app.use(nuxt.render)

       app.listen('/tmp/nginx.socket', () => {
         console.log("Signalling nginx buildpack to start listening")
         fs.openSync('/tmp/app-initialized', 'w')
       })
     })
}
```

NGINX :

```
daemon off;
#Heroku dynos have at least 4 cores.
worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>;

events {
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex on;
    worker_connections <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKER_CONNECTIONS'] || 1024 %>;
}

error_log stderr;
http {
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 512;

    server_tokens off;

    log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time 
    request_id=$http_x_request_id';
    access_log eroor;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;

    #Must read the body in 5 seconds.
    client_body_timeout 5;

    upstream app_server {
        server unix:/tmp/nginx.socket fail_timeout=0;
    }

    map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
      "text/html"                 epoch;
      "text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch;
      default                     off;
  }

  client_max_body_size 200M;

    server {
        client_max_body_size 200M;
        listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
        server_name localhost;
        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }
    }
}
```

Buildpack:
heroku/nodejs
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx.git

Stack :
heroku-20

Procfile :

```
web: bin/start-nginx nuxt start
```

Comment: It says `buildpack=nginx at=app-initialization` and not working. used heroku stack-22 btw. Buildpack is this one: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku-community/nginx.tgz

Comment: and my package.json -> start command looks like: `"start": "node server.js"` and my procfile calls it like: `web: bin/start-nginx yarn start`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited the answer please check above